# setValue is duplicating value on all inputs instead of the input on focus

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Im experimenting an issue with my inputs, Im getting the objects with the values of the inputs in an `Array` from a `fetch` in another component called `customFieldsUpdate`, I want to update the value of the objects in case there is non or if it want to be changed.

The issue is that im getting all in place but when I type in one `<input/>` all the inputs values are being replaced and not just thatone im trying to edit. to be more specific, right now I have 5 inputs, if I type in one of them, all of them changes. Im trying to implement something like a `this` to keep the change only in the input on focus but im not getting it...
Here is my code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {CustomFieldsUpdate} from './customFieldsUpdate';

import {Col} from 'reactstrap';

export function CustomFieldsList({list}) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(false);

  function handleChange(e){
    setValue(e.target.value) // <----- Here Im trying to do something like this.setValue(e.target.value) 
                             // or setValue(e.target.this.value)?
  }
  console.log(list);

  return (
    <>
      <form>
        <ul className={'list-group border-0'}>

          {list.map(item => (  // <--- Here I generate the inputs that comes from the fetch

            <li className={'list-group-item d-flex border-0'} key={item.id}>
               <Col md={2}>
                <label>{item.id}</label>
               </Col>
               <Col md={10}>

                <input
                  className="form-control"
                  type="text"
                  value={value || item.value} //<---- and here show value if there is one or set the newone
                  onChange={handleChange} /> // <--- Im trying to handle change here 

               </Col>
            </li>
          ))}

        </ul>
        <CustomFieldsUpdate />
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

The inputs generates depending on the quantity of objects I get from the JSON fetch thats why im mapping them... maybe thats not right? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have list of inputs with **one** `value` and `setValue`property for all inputs list.
You need to create one component with one input and one value and setValue. And in container mapping this components like:

`CustomItem.js`

```
export function CustomItem({item}) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(false);

  function handleChange(e){
    setValue(e.target.value);                           
  }

  return (
    <>
            <li className={'list-group-item d-flex border-0'} key={item.id}>
               <Col md={2}>
                <label>{item.id}</label>
               </Col>
               <Col md={10}>

                <input
                  className="form-control"
                  type="text"
                  value={value || item.value} 
                  onChange={handleChange} /> 
               </Col>
    </>
  );
}
```

`CustomList`

```
import CustomItem from './CustomItem';

export function CustomFieldsList({list}) {

  return (
    <>
      <form>
        <ul className={'list-group border-0'}>

          {list.map(item => (  
             <CustomItem item={item}/>
            ))}

        </ul>
        <CustomFieldsUpdate />
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```